# Keep parent menu highlighted while hovering over submenus

Tags: css, wordpress, sass

I need to keep the parent parent menu item highlighted while hovering over its submenu items with level1 and 2. I am having problem because the link of level1 and level2 are different colors.

This never happens because seems like as soon as the mouse leaves the menu item and gets over the submenu, the browser styles it to its default style. Any help appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Follow my code in SCSS to study:

SCSS:

```
.menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;

    li {
        margin-left: 30px;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;

        &:first-child {
            margin: 0;
        }

        &.current_page_item a {
            color: #00a7cf;
        }
    }
    a {
        color: #0a343a;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        letter-spacing: 0.01em;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        white-space: nowrap;

        &:hover {
            color: #00a7cf;
        }

    }

    & > li:hover > .sub-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    & > li > .sub-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: -35px;
        padding: 40px 35px;
        background-color: #0b4e78;
        list-style: none;
        z-index: 1001;
        display: none;

        &::before {
            content: '';
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 0 9px 10px 9px;
            border-color: transparent transparent #0b4e78 transparent;
            position: absolute;
            top: -10px;
            left: 80px;
        }

        & > li:hover > .sub-menu {
            display: block;
        }

        & > li > .sub-menu {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            padding: 40px 35px;
            background-color: #0b4e78;
            list-style: none;
            width: calc(100% + 100vw);
            min-height: 250px;
            padding-left: calc(100% + 50px);
            z-index: -1;
            display: none;

            &::before {
                content: '';
                height: calc(100% - 40px);
                position: absolute;
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
                width: 1px;
                top: 0;
                transform: translateX(-50px);
            }

            a {
                font-size: 1.2em;
                font-weight: 100;
                color: #fff;

                &:hover {
                    color: #00a7cf;
                }

            }
        }

        li {
            margin: 0;
            position: unset;
        }

        a {
            color: #00a7cf;

            &:hover {
                color: #fff;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu-principal" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-20 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-71"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/">INSTITUCIONAL</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-80"><a href="#">INSTITUCIONAL</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-95" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-95"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/institucional/sobre-nos/">Sobre nós</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-94" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-94"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/institucional/historico/">Histórico</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-93" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-93"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/institucional/conselho-de-administracao/">Conselho de Administração</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/institucional/entidades-parceiras/">Entidades Parceiras</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-91" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/institucional/estatuto-social/">Estatuto Social</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-90"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/institucional/principios-eticos-e-codigo-de-conduta/">Princípios Éticos e Código de Conduta</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-89" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-89"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/institucional/noticias/">Notícias</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-79"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/comites/">COMITÊS</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-81" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-81"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/associados/">ASSOCIADOS</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-18" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-18"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/educacional/">EDUCACIONAL</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-98"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/institucional/sobre-nos/">Sobre nós</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-96" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-96"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/institucional/conselho-de-administracao/">Conselho de Administração</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-97" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-97"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/institucional/historico/">Histórico</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-17" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-17"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/certificacao-e-credenciamento/">CERTIFICAÇÃO E CREDENCIAMENTO</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-16" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-16"><a href="http://localhost/ancord/contato/">CONTATO</a>     </li>
</ul>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/marcoriesco/pen/jxVaEz

Comment: can you post your html also?

Comment: I'll post, just a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for this:

```
.menu-item:hover > a {
  color: #00a7cf;
}
.sub-menu > li:hover > a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Your submenu is inside the "li" tag, so you should take the hover over the "li" which is the parent of all the submenu content, and then style the menu link.

To maintain the structure of your code, it would look something like this:

```
.menu {
  > li {
    &:hover {
      > a {
        color: #00a7cf;
      }
    }
    .sub-menu > li {
      &:hover > a {
        color: #fff;
      }
    }
  }
}
```